# Han Solo "Dusting Crops"

Tags: star-wars

In Star Wars: A New Hope, we hear Han Solo chide Luke for his lack of understanding of hyperspace travel. However, his remark...

> ***Traveling through hyperspace ain't like dusting crops, boy!***

...has me a bit confused.

This snide remark would make sense to 20th century Earth audiences, but is there any canon context for crop-dusting on Tatooine?

Comment: Tatooine is a very sandy place and deposits often accumulate on the leaves of crops which, if left unmitigated, would inhibit photosynthesis. It follows that Luke, like many Tatooinite farmers must, literally, *dust* his crops to prevent this buildup.

Comment: But Luke's uncle was a moisture farmer. The idea of dusting off water seems implausible, even in the context of the Procrustean Canonization that goes on on this board.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

## Han is probably not referring to Tatooine

Because of the extreme environment, crops were mainly grown underground on Tatooine, and irrigated using moisture from [moisture farms](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Moisture_farm), like the one owned by Owen and Beru.

Han is likely drawing instead from his upbringing on Corellia — this is an Earth-like world with farmland outside of its major cities, and agriculture is one of the main industries.  (See [here](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Corellia).)

There would likely be a need for crop dusting and topdressing on Corellia — this includes seed planting on a wide scale, fertilizer distribution, and pesticide application.

Regarding the latter, Corellia seems to teem with wildlife and insects.  A selection of the native species is listed [here](http://duckduckgo.com/2/c/Species_of_Corellia?ia=list).  Some of them certainly have the potential to damage crops.

**In any case, crop dusting is an efficient technique associated with industrial-scale agriculture.  The Star Wars galaxy might have better (or worse) technology for this than we do, depending on the planet, but there is no reason for it to not occur on a planet like Corellia, which would inform Han's perspective on the matter.**

Comment: Corellia is one planet I'd really like to see in the new movies. I played the original Star Wars MMORPG (Galaxies), and I really enjoyed exploring Corellia. I think it would be nice to see the planet close up in the new additions to the saga.

Comment: Which means Luke might not have even understood what Han was talking about... "Dusting crops... like... with a duster?"